# Exportar datos desde MySQL a CSV con PHP en un determinado formato

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Veamos, tengo una tabla en MySQL que se llama `id_pedidos_agencia` con la siguiente estructura:

```
IdPedido VARCHAR (20)
```

Los IdPedido son algo de este estilo `12345678-A`. Quiero sacarlos desde MySQL a CSV, a un CSV que tenga el siguiente formato:

```
mp_order_id;seller_internal_order_id;currier;tracking_number
12345678-A;12345678-A;;
```

Es decir, le tengo que poner primero esa cabecera y luego cada IdPedido duplicarlo por dos. Mis dudas:

a) Es la primera vez que hago esto, no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo y lo que he buscado por Internet no me ha resuelto gran cosa, añadir que he de hacer esto desde código PHP. 
b) En el CSV, entiendo que el primer `;` que separa a los dos IdPedido es el separador pero... ¿por qué hay dos `;` al final de la línea, ¿no bastaría uno?

Gracias.

Comment: Para tu duda **(a)**, hay ya varias preguntas en el sitio que hablan sobre escribir archivos CSV desde PHP, si buscas en la barra superior poniendo esto **`[php] csv`** [encontrarás resultados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20csv). Para tu duda **(b)**, hay dos `;` al final porque en esa línea el valor correspondiente a `seller_internal_order_id` está en blanco. Pero es incorrecto, la línea debe terminar por salto de línea, no por `;`

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto de una forma bastante sencilla:

```
$file = fopen("idpedidosagencia.txt", "w"); //Creo el fichero

fwrite($file, "mp_order_id;seller_internal_order_id;currier;tracking_number" . PHP_EOL);

foreach($idPedidos as $key => $value){
    fwrite($file, "$value[0]".";"."$value[0]".";;". PHP_EOL);
}
```

Simplemente si tienes un array con todos los id de los pedidos ($idPedidos) pues se puede escribir como un fichero de texto y ya está.